# Getting logo to disappear with JQuery

Tags: jquery

Sorry if this is a noob question. I am relatively new to JQuery and manipulting the DOM.

What is am trying to achieve is to get the logo in the header to disappear when the user slides down about 10% down the page. I found some very useful tutorials online, but they have proved unsuccessful.

The logo:

```
<div id="logo" style="padding-bottom: 30px;">
    <a href="index.php">
        <img src="http://localhost/website/logo.png">
    </a>
</div>
```

The JQuery:

```
<script>
    $("body").scroll( function() {
        var value = $(this).scrollTop();
        if ( value > 100 )
            $("#logo").css("display", "none");        
    });
</script>
```

Any edits, recommendations or educational resources are greatly appreciated

Comment: And what browser would you be using for this, as the body doesn't always have the scrollbar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `window`, not `body`

```
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
    var value = $(this).scrollTop();
    if ( value < 100 )
        $("#logo").css("display", "none");        
});
```

To toggle the logo back again when scrolling up

```
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
    $("#logo").toggle($(this).scrollTop() < 100);
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/b8sX9/)